# Get last item in SPLIT array using SQL in AWS Athena and PrestoDB

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I'm trying to get the last item in an array after I split a string. I'd do this easily in Javascript using `url.split('//')[url.split('//').length-1]`

But how to do in SQL running on AWS Athena (which I believe is actually Proton)

```
// imagine a url is like 'http://www.google.com'

SELECT * SPLIT(url, '//')[2]
FROM table
```

Would result in `www.google.com`

But in some instance there is no result, so I need to use `[1]` and not `[2]`.

```
// imagine a url is like 'www.google.com'

SELECT * SPLIT(url, '//')[2]
FROM table
```

This would result in `Error`.

How do I get the last item in the array?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a non-capturing group in regular expression

`select regexp_extract('www.google.com', '(?:https?://)?(.*)',1)`

and

`select regexp_extract('http://www.google.com', '(?:https?://)?(.*)',1)`

will both return `www.google.com`

Please note that the protocol can be either HTTP or HTTPS and the above regex also expects to have the `s` or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

Use the `element_at` function, both will give the desired output:

```
SELECT ELEMENT_AT(SPLIT('http://www.google.com', '//'), -1)
SELECT ELEMENT_AT(SPLIT('www.google.com', '//'), -1)
```

The second option is using the `slice` function to get a subset of the array. Both will give the desired output:

```
SELECT SLICE(SPLIT('http://www.google.com', '//'), -1, 1)[1]
SELECT SLICE(SPLIT('www.google.com', '//'), -1, 1)[1]
```

- -1 mentions the first index of the sub-array
- 1 is the length of the sub-array

To read more about how `slice` function works: https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#slice